# How to match URL in PCRE regex that does not contain certain prefix

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a list of strings that I need to filter through using regex. Some of the strings may contain URLS in the form of '(random_chars).(random_chars).(random_chars).(random_chars)...' etc.

I am trying to create a regex that will find such URLS but ignore URLS where the first set of (random_chars) does not match 'java'.

For example the strings below:

- "test string (test.url.com) abcdef java.lang.Assertion uvwxyz www.google.com abcdef"

  > I'd expect it to match test.url.com and www.google.com but not java.lang.Assertion
- "another test string /abc/xyz/lib/def/GH.tr test 200."

  > I wouldn't want it to match GH.tr

My current regex will match the below:

- test.url.com
- java.lang.Assertion
- www.google.com
- GH.tr

This is my current regex, and I have attempted to use a negative lookahead:

`(?!java)(?:(?:\w+\.)+[\w]+)`

What have I missed with my regex?

Comment: Thanks Emma, I have been using that tool to try and help me. You are correct in saying that I don't want java or GH, but I want to match any other URL and ignore anything else in the complete string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get those matches because the negative lookahead `(?!java)` asserts that what is directly on the right is not java.

That is false when the position is right before `java.lang.Assertion`, so that does not match.

But then moving to the `j`, then the assertion is true because on the right is now `ava.lang.Assertion` so that will match.

One option could be to match what you don't want to keep using [`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex). Then match what you want to keep.

```
\bjava(?:\.\w+)+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<!/)\b\w+(?:\.\w+)+
```

That will match

- `\bjava(?:\.\w+)+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Pattern to match what you don't want to keep
- `|` Or
- `(?<!/)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a forward slash
- `\b\w+(?:\.\w+)+` Pattern that you want to match starting with a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yotJ59/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/bLsc1)